# Cypress: Where does the authentication token go for an API request?

Tags: api, authentication, cypress

I am trying to request data through an API that requires authentification. I have the token and I know how to implement it using a manual tool such as postman...
[image: postman API authentication]

How do I format the authentication using Cypress?

```
    it('GET - read', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://mailtrap.io/api/v1/inboxes/123/messages?page=1&last_id=&useremail',
        headers: {
            Key: 'Api-Token',
            Value: '1234'
        }
    })
})

})
```

Response:

```
The response we got was:

Status: 401 - Unauthorized
```

Comment: Can you replace key with Key and try once.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Tried it but unfortunately, I get the same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Mailtrap documentation](https://mailtrap.docs.apiary.io/#), sending an header `Api-Token: {api_token}` should send authenticated requests. You can write:

```
cy.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://mailtrap.io/api/v1/inboxes/123/messages?page=1&last_id=&useremail',
    headers: {
        'Api-Token': 'Your Token value' //Replace with real token
    },
    failOnStatusCode: false
}).then((res) => {
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200) //Replace with releveant 2xx response code
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting a 401 response -  'body: {error: "Your api token or JWT is invalid"}'. I know the token is valid because it works through postman. So I assume there is a problem with where and how it wants the token to be formatted?

Comment: I have updated my answer. can you please check.